# WPS Office a16 install Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wps-office

I was using WPS Office a15 beautifully on 14.04. Today, a box advertising a16 opened when I opened WPS word processor. I downloaded and tried installing via gdeb and software center but nothing happened. I redownloaded a15 and it installed correctly. Any idea if a16 is buggy?

Comment: Do you need some new functions or bug fixes in the new version? If not, just stay with the current one.

Comment: I installed a16p1_i386.deb (p1=patch 1) and it worked wonderfully.

Comment: Great! You should write an answer with the installation steps and accept it, since others with the same problem may stumble upon your question.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, as far as I know it has a problem showing the menu icons so the page tells you to install some sort of a patch, a file named "fix-menu.sh".

I tried installing the patch from terminal but it seemed not to be working  so I went for the second option, which was re downloading and installing a16 again, didn't worked for me nether.

Final option (this worked for me):

sudo apt-get remove wps-office

sudo apt-get purge wps-office

sudo apt-get update

re downloaded the wps a16 package and reinstalled it.

Even though I used the command purge some configurations seem to have survived the massacre, Custom dictionary and saving format preferences among others.

Good Luck! :D

Comment: Thank you for your response. As mentioned above, I installed a16p1_i386.deb (p1=patch 1) and it worked wonderfully.